# Display and Software Icons not showing

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, gui

I have run upgrade command on Ubuntu 16.04. While downloading, I shut down my Laptop. When I switch on and login, the display and icons are not visible and blank screen is being shown with icon moving on mouse.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `var/log/apt/term.log` section for that upgrade and after.

Comment: Unable to send because screen is blank.

Comment: Then use a TTY (look it up)